# Grouping data by latest entry

Tags: r, group-by

I have the following data

```
pt_id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
visit_id <- c(11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,31,32,33,34,35,41,42,43,44)
visit <- c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020)
mydata <- data.frame(pt_id, visit_id, visit)
mydata
```

I have been provided only the year for the 'visit' variable, however, it has been ordered from oldest to newest for each 'pt_id'. I want to create a new column ranking the rows in descending order grouped by'pt_id'.

Desired output:

```
  pt_id   visit_id visit Row_rank
1      1       11  2019   5
2      1       12  2019   4
3      1       13  2019   3
4      1       14  2019   2
5      1       15  2020   1
6      2       21  2019   3
7      2       22  2019   2
8      2       23  2020   1
9      3       31  2019   5
10     3       32  2019   4
11     3       33  2019   3
12     3       34  2019   2
13     3       35  2020   1
14     4       41  2019   4
15     4       42  2020   3
16     4       43  2020   2
17     4       44  2020   1
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Eric Krantz I have edited to add the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use `visit_id` for the new variable, instead of `order`, since `order` is a function in base R.

```
mydata_lstvst <- mydata %>%
    arrange(pt_id, visit, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(pt_id) %>% 
    mutate(order = n() - row_number() + 1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    arrange(pt_id, visit, desc(order)) %>% 
    filter(order == 1)

mydata_lstvst
```

EDIT: Updated to address comment (filter on visit_id == 1).

Comment: Thanks! I am now trying to code for grouping the data by 'pt_id' for 'visit_n' with value 1. I am not able to write the desired output in comment. Let me know if you can code for it.

Comment: Add `%>% filter(order == 1)` to the end of that code.

Comment: Getting this error ```Error in order == 1 : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types```

Comment: So I did a subset for visit_n with value 1 :) ```mydata_lstvst_1 <- subset(mydata_lstvst, visit_n == 1)``` Much thanks!

Comment: Ah, the issue was that I was using `order` for the variable name and you were sill using `visit_id`. `order` is a function in base R. It will work but has to be consistent throughout (`order` has to be a variable in the df, otherwise R is trying to filter by the function name).

Comment: I realized the previous code messes up with the order for multiple visits in the same year. The code gives the lowest rank to the most recent visit and vice versa for the oldest one in the same year. But it should be the other way round. I have updated my df with a new variable to reflect this error in the main question. I have also updated the desired output.

Comment: Fixed it. Try it now.